# Designing a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to design a table in R. Below the format that I aim for. Besides the [expss](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/vignettes/tables-with-labels.html) library is there a nicer way to do this?

[image]

Sample data used to create the table:

```
 df<-structure(list(X1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "At least 35 hours of paid work", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "More than 35 hours of paid work", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Most common start time<ff>", 
    NA, NA, "Most common duration (at most common start time)", "Mean Duration across the whole period", 
    "Most common start time<ff>", "Most common duration (at most common start time)", 
    "Mean Duration across the whole period", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        `Main job` = c("04:00", "?", "07:50", "07:00", NA, NA, "120", 
        "00:43:06", "07:00", "180; 360", "00:52:25", NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X4 = c("08:00", "?", "11:50", "09:00", NA, NA, "240", 
        "00:58:42", "09:00", "240", "00:57:04", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
        ), X5 = c("12:00", "?", "15:50", "13:00", NA, NA, "120", 
        "00:55:03", "13:00", "120", "01:00:55", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
        ), X6 = c("16:00", "?", "19:50", "16:00", NA, NA, "60", "00:46:30", 
        "16:00", "120", "00:36:01", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c("20:00", 
        "?", "23:50", "22:00", NA, NA, "180", "00:23:30", "21:00", 
        "40", "00:26:36", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X8 = c("00:00", "?", 
        "03:50", "01:00;01:40; 02:30;02:40;03:00:00", NA, NA, "180 (at 01:00)", 
        "00:14:30", "01:00", "180; 60", "00:12:36", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), Sleep = c("04:00", "?", "07:50", "04:00", NA, NA, "190", 
        "00:30:05", "05:10", "50; 110", "00:49:01", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X10 = c("08:00", "?", "11:50", "10:00", NA, NA, "180", 
        "00:27:22", "10:00", "180; 360", "00:54:35", NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X11 = c("12:00", "?", "15:50", "14:00", NA, NA, 
        "120", "00:22:26", "15:00", "120", "00:17:15", NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X12 = c("16:00", "?", "19:50", "16:00", NA, NA, 
        "90", "00:11:52", "18:00", "60", "00:16:22", NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X13 = c("20:00", "?", "23:50", "22:00", NA, NA, 
        "360", "00:48:39", "22:00", "360", "00:44:32", NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X14 = c("00:00", "?", "03:50", "01:00", NA, NA, 
        "180", "00:19:16", "01:00", "180", "00:19:39", NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), `TV and DVD` = c("04:00", "?", "07:50", "07:50", 
        NA, NA, "30", "00:06:28", "06:30", "30", "00:06:28", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA), X16 = c("08:00", "?", "11:50", "11:00", 
        NA, NA, "50; 120", "00:06:44", "08:20", "40", "00:06:44", 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X17 = c("12:00", "?", "15:50", "13:00", 
        NA, NA, "120", "00:09:40", "15:50", "70;80;90", "00:09:40", 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X18 = c("16:00", "?", "19:50", "19:00", 
        NA, NA, "60", "00:17:41", "19:00", "180", "00:17:41", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA), X19 = c("20:00", "?", "23:50", "21:00", 
        NA, NA, "60", "00:10:46", "20:00", "120", "00:10:46", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA), X20 = c("00:00", "?", "03:50", "00:10", 
        NA, NA, "50", "00:05:50", "00:10", "50", "00:05:50", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), spec = structure(list(
        cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), `Main job` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), Sleep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X11 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X13 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X14 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), `TV and DVD` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X16 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X17 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X19 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), X20 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
        "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: You could use htmltable package : http://www.lyzander.com/r/2018/01/05/tablehtml-vesion-1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `gt` package `tab_spanner` function for adding labels to columns :

https://yutannihilation.github.io/gt/reference/tab_spanner.html

For rows , you could use `tab_row_group` :

[https://yutannihilation.github.io/gt/reference/tab_row_group.html]

For exploring `gt` functions :

https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/index.html

Another option is with `flextable` package .